# Only Static IMAGES not showing up on Django application? Deployed to Heroku and using S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a finished Django application that I am trying to push to production using Heroku and S3 but I have run into some confusion.

So far I have pushed the project to Heroku using git, I have pushed my Postgres database to the HerokuPostgres and that is working, and I have uploaded my static files (including css and images) to S3.

Currently, when you go to the Heroku application (https://foobar.herokuapp.com/) the page loads, the css works, and the database works. However, the static images are not showing up. Why could this be?

Here are a few lines from my **settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '###',
        'USER': '###',
        'PASSWORD': '###',
        'HOST': '###',
        'PORT': '###',
    }
}

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://foobar')}

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/textchange/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# STATIC_ROOT = '/home/joe/Documents/exchange/Texchange/textchange/static/'

# STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'foobar'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'foobar'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

I am just looking for some guidance as to why the images aren't showing up.

Note: Images uploaded by users are being uploaded to S3 and being displayed on the site but still my static images do not show up. How could uploaded images work fine but no other static images work?

Comment: Make sure your STATIC_URL is pointed to your S3 address.

Comment: It does. I know this because my css files are working fine and they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

To enable images to load when DEBUG=False, do the following in your urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.views.static import serve
```

and then add those two urls in urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

assuming that your `MEDIA_URL = 'media'` and `STATIC_URL='static'`

Answer (score 0):

serving static files is actually one of the things that Django makes incredibly complicated and fraught with hazard. the recommended way is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/, and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/. I ended up making a show_static view and a pattern that matched the static pages, so just put url(static_pattern, views.show_static) in my urls.py.

Comment: That doesn't help too much with this though. When I was working locally all my static files worked fine. Now the ONLY thing that doesn't work is static images in production.

Comment: I'm starting to figure it out. I am not referencing images properly in my html.

Comment: @joe how did you refernce them? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @losee Still having the problem? I can take a look Edit: What exactly isn't working? Are you also using S3? How did I reference my static_url, media_url or how did i reference the images in the html?